# Isolated Plateau quest not showing progress

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So, early in the game, you're told to look around and mark 3 shrines on your map.

I've marked the 3 yellow shrines (and accidentally marked the one I'd already completed), but talking to the old man acts like I'm having trouble finding them.

Am I supposed to just go complete the shrines now or is the game just being finicky with my pin placement on the map?

Comment: It's a bit confusing when he doesn't seem to say "great, you've marked all 3, we can proceed with the game now and I'll stop bugging you!"   I've grown used to games pestering me about the main story, so I'm happy this game doesn't force that down your throat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that you need to go and do the shrines now that you've marked them.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I haven't tried it yet because I took a dinner break first... after going to the wrong area and having my best two weapons break.

Comment: On a side note, I'll find out in a few minutes whether the game auto-saves when you hit the game over screen.

Comment: You can just manually save also.